# How do I turn this into a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

How do I turn the array `a = [[[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], [[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]]]` into a numpy matrix of the form

```
[[1,2,3,4],
[5,6,7,8],
[9,10,11,12],
[13,14,15,16]]
```

? I have tried `np.bmat(a)` to no avail. When I do that, I get a 2x6 matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.array` to construct the array, then `reshape` to mold it into the right shape:

```
>>> np.array([[[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], [[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]]]).reshape((4,4))
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```